# How to add free unpartitioned space to the main / partition in Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

I want to add free un-partitioned space to / partition. my partition is not in LVM.

Please refer to my [cfdik output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkUn0.jpg) and my fdisk details:

```
fdisk /dev/sda

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.31.1).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors

Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disklabel type: dos

Disk identifier: 0x001c4825

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type

/dev/sda1  *        2048 12584959 12582912   6G 83 Linux

/dev/sda2       12587006 20969471  8382466   4G  5 Extended

/dev/sda5       12587008 20969471  8382464   4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Command (m for help): F

Unpartitioned space /dev/sda: 90 GiB, 96637812736 bytes, 188745728 sectors

Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

   Start       End   Sectors Size

20969472 209715199 188745728  90G  

Command (m for help):
```

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark and up-arrow icons just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: status please...

Comment: I have just tried with your suggestion, @heynnema, and it is working. Deleted the swapp partition, it is just running with 8 GB RAM in VMWare.

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **delete** /dev/sda5
- **delete** /dev/sda2
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sda1 all the way right
- click the Apply icon
- boot to Ubuntu
- there may be a slight delay in booting due to the missing /dev/sda5 swap
- create a new /swapfile, using the `terminal` app
- `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096`
- `sudo chmod 600 /swapfile`
- `sudo mkswap /swapfile`
- `sudo swapon /swapfile`

**Edit /etc/fstab...**

`sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab`

Replace the one line that has the word "**swap**" in it with:

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0 0
```

Then **reboot** to assure that everything works as expected.

Use the `free -h` command to confirm / and /swapfile sizes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to expand sda1 and make use of the unallocated space at the end of the drive then try the following.

Boot the system as @vanadium suggests with a live disk.

Using GParted move sda2 and sda5 to the extreme right.

Using GParted you should then be able to expand sda1 into the unallocated space between sda1 and sda2.

Comment: Indeed I unfortunatelly misunderstood the question, so I deleted the answer